# Как сделать AUTO_INCREMENT или NOT NULL в YQL?

Tags: sql, yandex-cloud, ydb

Делаю DB для игры, но застрял на создании таблицы - не могу поставить аттрибут AUTO_INCREMENT или NOT NULL.

Вот что пока написал:

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
    id Uint64,
    login Utf8,
    password Utf8,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Но если делаю так:

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
    id Uint64 AUTO_INCREMENT,
    login Utf8,
    password Utf8,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Тогда мне выкидывает ошибку `Unexpected token absence : Missing RPAREN`. Кто знаком с YQL, пожалуйста подскажите что можно сделать

Comment: У вас крайне странная постановка вопроса «AUTO_INCREMENT или NOT NULL». Это не связанные между собой вещи. NOT NULL описан в первом же примере документации https://ydb.tech/ru/docs/yql/reference/syntax/create_table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак.
Используйте внешний сервис (или таблицу) для этого.

https://nikolaymatrosov.medium.com/%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B2-yandex-datadase-d9933ec0b1be